# need to know if this is possible in SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server

I have sales orders with quotes against them however new quote revisions are made and sometimes the sales orders don't get updated. So i need to write query to find any orders that don't have the most updated quote.

Currently this is done in excel but i want to be able to run a query to get the same results.

**MY SQL or SQL Server.**

Table and fields
`Sales order lines` - sales order ID / current quote ID 
`Quotes` - Quote ID

The sales order ID is a numerical field XXXXX.
The quote ID fields are like 12345 and if a new revision is created it a new quote is added and called 12345-A it goes up alphabetically per revision.

What i want to see is

```
Sales order ID | Current Quote ID | Latest Quote ID
---------------|------------------|-----------------
53849          | 12345            | 12345-D
```

Please let me know if this is possible

[image: Example Data]

Comment: Please add actual sample data to your question and also tell us which _version_ of SQL you are using (e.g. MySQL, SQL Server, Access).  "SQL" is just a language, not an actual product.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. I have edited my post. i hope it helps

Comment: What comes first, the Order or the Quote? It seems like it's the wrong way round.

Comment: Yes, I think this is possible in SQL. MSSQL or MySQL.

Comment: I'm unclear how the tables would look in sql?  Could you explain a bit more around how the data looks?  are the 3 columns already sales order ID, Current Quote ID and Latest Quote ID?  If so, it's just WHERE `current_quote_id` != `latest_quote_id`

Comment: It is possible, yes. You want to take the integer part of a quote revision number and see whether its the latest revision for the quote. Rather than doing this via string manipulation in SQL, however, you should fix your data model. If there are quotes and revisions, then these should be two separate columns - and even two separate tables maybe.

Comment: Hi guys, thanks for the replies.

The Sales Order and Current Quote ID sit on the Sales order table.

The the Latest Quote ID is actually just the Quite ID from the Quotes table.

So i need SQL to get the latest Quote ID revision from the quotes table and compare it to the current of the Sales order table.

I hope this better describes what i need.

Answer (score 1):

This is too long for a comment and is not an answer.

I am totally baffled by the question.  Your sample results have something called a `Sales Order ID` with a value of `53849`.  I see no `53849` in the sample data.  Of course, I might be missing it.  But I can't search an image.

Then:

> The quote ID fields are like 12345.

However, *none* of the values in the `Quote ID` field look like this.

The first four columns are not labelled, so you have not communicated what the data looks like or how to identify the "old" and "new" values.

I would recommend that you ask a *new* question, with clear sample data as a *text table* (and also a fiddle is very helpful).  And clear desired results.

Comment: Thanks for your comment Gordon. I do apologies for the complexity and messy question. As suiggested i'll ask a new question with everything correctly laid out.

Comment: I'm glad I wasn't the only one who was struggling to find the required data within the image!

Answer (score 0):

How about something like the below?

```
SELECT sales_order_id 'Sales order ID',
    current_quote_id 'Current Quote ID',
    latest_quote_id 'Latest Quote ID'
FROM orders
WHERE current_quote_id != latest_quote_id
```

Answer (score 0):

[is it what you want](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1CHfl.jpg)

Here is the syntax

```
Select * Into #SalesOrderLine From (
    Select 'SO-001' [Sales Order ID], 'QUO-001' [Quote ID] Union All
    Select 'SO-002' [Sales Order ID], 'QUO-002' [Quote ID] Union All
    Select 'SO-003' [Sales Order ID], 'QUO-003' [Quote ID] Union All
    Select 'SO-004' [Sales Order ID], 'QUO-004' [Quote ID] Union All
    Select 'SO-005' [Sales Order ID], 'QUO-005' [Quote ID] 
) A

Select * Into #Quotes  From (
    Select 'QUO-001-A' [Quote ID] Union All
    Select 'QUO-001-B' [Quote ID] Union All
    Select 'QUO-001-C' [Quote ID] Union All
    Select 'QUO-001-D' [Quote ID] Union All
    Select 'QUO-002-A' [Quote ID] Union All
    Select 'QUO-002-B' [Quote ID] Union All
    Select 'QUO-002-C' [Quote ID] 
) A

Select * From #SalesOrderLine
Select * From #Quotes

Select 
  [Sales Order ID], [Quote ID], 
( Select Top 1 [Quote ID] From #Quotes B 
  Where B.[Quote ID] like A.[Quote ID]+'%' 
  Order By B.[Quote ID] Desc) [Lastest Quote ID]
From #SalesOrderLine A
```

you need to see ones that don't match the latest.
Here's the syntax below

```
Select * From (
    Select 
      [Sales Order ID], [Quote ID], 
    ( Select Top 1 [Quote ID] From #Quotes B 
      Where B.[Quote ID] like A.[Quote ID]+'%' 
      Order By B.[Quote ID] Desc) [Lastest Quote ID]
    From #SalesOrderLine A
) DONE
Where [Quote ID] <> IsNull([Lastest Quote ID],'')
```

Comment: I have created a new question here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57508935/sql-code-assistance-for-finding-latest-record-based-on-id but looking at your answer YES this is what i'm looking for

Comment: Nice, 
if I can suggest your table #Quate must have a field [Sales Order ID],
so can have a best performance ( I Think )

Comment: Thanks for the script it works however, it's not bringing over what i need. It is only showing ones that match and are updated. I need to see ones that don't match the latest. If possible?

Comment: Yes possible, I have edited my post. Hope can help you.