# SQL code assistance for finding latest record based on ID

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server

This is a question off the back of my older question as it was unclear as to what i was looking for. Old questions can be found here: [need to know if this is possible in SQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57507536/need-to-know-if-this-is-possible-in-sql)

I have sales orders with quotes against them however new quote revisions are made and sometimes the sales orders don't get updated. So i need to write a query to find any orders that don't have the most updated quote.

Currently this is done in excel but i want to be able to run a query to get the same results.

MY SQL or SQL Server.

Table and fields
Sales order lines - sales order ID / current quote ID 
Quotes - Quote ID

The sales order ID is a numerical field XXXXX. The quote ID fields are like 12345 and if a new revision is created it a new quote is added and called 12345-A it goes up alphabetically per revision.

Example data

Sales Orders

```
omlSalesOrderID | omlQuoteID
53849           | 12345
31486           | 95648-A
12489           | 68745-D
68732           | 32149-E
```

Quotes

```
qmpQuoteID
12345   
12345-A 
12345-B 
95648   
95648-A 
95648-B 
95648-C 
68745   
68745-A 
68745-B 
68745-C 
68745-D 
32149   
32149-A 
32149-B 
32149-C 
32149-D 
32149-E
```

What i want to see is

```
Sales order ID | Current Quote ID | Latest Quote ID
---------------|------------------|-----------------
53849          | 12345            | 12345-B
31486          | 95648-A          | 95648-C
12489          | 68745-D          | 68745-D
68732          | 32149-E          | 32149-E
```

Comment: If it was me, and I had the authority to do so, I would fix the schema.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Table **Sales Order Line**

```
Select * Into #oml From (
    Select '53849' [omlSalesOrderID], '12345' [omlQuoteID] Union All
    Select '31486' [omlSalesOrderID], '95648-A' [omlQuoteID] Union All
    Select '12489' [omlSalesOrderID], '68745-D' [omlQuoteID] Union All
    Select '68732' [omlSalesOrderID], '32149-E' [omlQuoteID]
) A
```

Table **Quote**

```
Select * Into #qmp From (
    Select '12345' [qmpQuoteID] Union All
    Select '12345-A' [qmpQuoteID] Union All
    Select '12345-B' [qmpQuoteID] Union All
    Select '95648' [qmpQuoteID] Union All
    Select '95648-A' [qmpQuoteID] Union All
    Select '95648-B' [qmpQuoteID] Union All
    Select '95648-C' [qmpQuoteID] Union All
    Select '68745' [qmpQuoteID] Union All
    Select '68745-A' [qmpQuoteID] Union All
    Select '68745-B' [qmpQuoteID] Union All
    Select '68745-C' [qmpQuoteID] Union All
    Select '68745-D' [qmpQuoteID] Union All
    Select '32149' [qmpQuoteID] Union All
    Select '32149-A' [qmpQuoteID] Union All
    Select '32149-B' [qmpQuoteID] Union All
    Select '32149-C' [qmpQuoteID] Union All
    Select '32149-D' [qmpQuoteID] Union All
    Select '32149-E' [qmpQuoteID] 
) A
```

Here is the syntax query (Same with your result)

```
Select 
    *, 
    (Select Top 1 qmpQuoteID From #qmp 
        where qmpQuoteID like 
            Case When charindex('-',omlQuoteID) = 0 Then omlQuoteID 
                 Else substring(omlQuoteID,0,charindex('-',omlQuoteID)) End + '%' 
        order by qmpQuoteID Desc) qmpQuoteID
From #oml
```

Answer (score 1):

In MySQL, you can use `substring_index()` and aggregation:

```
select o.quoteId, o.salesorderid,
       max(q.quote_id)
from orders o left join
     quotes q
     on o.quoteId = substring_index(q.quoteId, '-', 1)
group by o.quoteId;
```

In SQL Server (or MySQL as well), you can use `LIKE` for the comparison:

```
select o.quoteId, o.salesorderid,
       max(q.quote_id)
from orders o left join
     quotes q
     on q.quoteId like concat(o.quoteId, '-%')
group by o.quoteId;
```

Comment: looks good but i have this problem

The column for max is all NULL.

this is the sql 

select omlSalesOrderID, omlQuoteID, max(qmpQuoteID) 
from SalesOrderLines left join Quotes on qmpQuoteID like concat(omlQuoteID, '-%') 
Group By omlQuoteID, omlSalesOrderID;

Comment: @Roborob86 . . . That means there are no matches between the two tables . . . which in turn means that the values do not line up as they would visually seem to.  Can you set up a fiddle of some sort?

Comment: ive managed to tweak it, so either all my order and quotes line up or it's not displaying differences, which i need to see. Sorry, i re-read my post. i need to be able to see ones that don't match only

Comment: The other thing that doesn't work is that the max isn't selecting the latest Quote

Answer (score 0):

Join and `group by omlSalesOrderID, omlQuoteID`:

```
select 
  s.omlSalesOrderID `Sales order ID`, 
  s.omlQuoteID `Current Quote ID`,
  max(q.qmpQuoteID) `Latest Quote ID`
from salesorders s left join quotes q
on substring_index(concat(s.omlQuoteID, '-'), '-', 1) = substring_index(concat(q.qmpQuoteID, '-'), '-', 1)
group by s.omlSalesOrderID, s.omlQuoteID
```

Works for MySQL.
See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.6&fiddle=158c508e0137ef1841f75eece51a2157).
Results:

```
> Sales order ID | Current Quote ID | Latest Quote ID
> -------------: | :--------------- | :--------------
>          12489 | 68745-D          | 68745-D        
>          31486 | 95648-A          | 95648-C        
>          53849 | 12345            | 12345-B        
>          68732 | 32149-E          | 32149-E
```

Answer (score 0):

This gives you excepted results

```
select salesorderID as `Sales order ID`, 
       salesquoteID as `Current Quote ID`, 
       latestquoteID as `Latest Quote ID`
from(
     select substring_index(q.quoteID,'-',1) as nos, 
            max(substring_index(q.quoteID,'-',-1)) as alp, 
            max(q.quoteID) as latestquoteID,
            id, salesorderID, s.quoteID as salesquoteID                                                        
     from salesorder s
     left join quotes q 
     on substring_index(s.quoteID,'-',1) = substring_index(q.quoteID,'-',1)
     group by nos, s.id
) as sales 
order by id asc;
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/28a85a/1

https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/pavgTVPfHgrWP4Ph5G7rif/4